# l value required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I'm trying to populate several arrays with the same randomly selected integer but I keep getting the error in the subject line. Here is my code:

```
while(i++ < arraySize){
        randInt = (int)random()%100;
        originalArray++ = randInt;
        ascendingOrderArray++ = randInt;
        descendingOrderArray++ = randInt;
    }
```

Why is this error occurring in this context? From my understanding this code is identical to assigning randInt to the three arrays and then incrementing their pointers at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are trying to assign a value to a number -- to the address of an array. A number is an rvalue, not an lvalue, so it fails.

```
originalArray++ = randInt;
```

Here, you are assigning a value to a memory location -- the address obtained by dereferencing a pointer. This is a lvalue, and so it succeeds:

```
*originalArray++ = randInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `originalArray`, `ascendingOrderArray` and `descendingOrderArray` are pointers of type `int *` and `randInt` is of type `int`, you have to de-reference the pointer when assigning. For example `*originalArray++ = randInt;`. That will de-reference the pointer yielding the "lvalue" you can assign to, assign the value of `randInt` to it (to whenver `originalArray` pointer points to), and increment the pointer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

original++ is not an object, and so you can't store a value in it.